# Intellij: Build successful but error in class `cannot resolve symbol`

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

In my android project, the build is successful and the app works on the device but this error keeps appearing in the java classes for android support v7 and I can't do any actual coding.

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

I have invalidated the cache and restarted the ide many times.
I have re-imported the project many times as well

I'm out of idea. The support repository are installed. Might be there is something I am missing.

The android support version I'm using is 23.4.0

The library is listed in the list of external libraries

Help!!

Comment: Have you added design library 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'??

Comment: @akhilRao I'm not using the design library

Comment: @user2798694 Please show your build.gradle where you've added these dependencies

Comment: maybe try rebuild